# Moved files within Internal Storage and file can't be accessed from android

Tags: linux, file-transfer, mtp, 8.1-oreo

I have Moto G S5 (Android 8.1). I connected it to my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04). I moved some files (about 4 Gb) from a folder in internal storage to root folder of the internal storage.

Transfer happened succesfully. But the File manager of android doesn't show those files in the root folder. And I can access those files from my laptop, but when I try to open it. It shows `Unknown MTP error`. The SD card capacity when viewed from Android has decreased by 4 Gb (same as those files), but when I see the SD card capacity through Ubuntu the capacity remains intact.

Please suggest me some steps to recover those files. I tried copying those files back to the original location, but I get the same MTP error.

Comment: raw ideas: a) use a terminal emulator or b) `adb shell` to gain shell access, then use the `mv` command to move the files back to their original location. I wouldn't trust MTP farther than I can throw my house. To my experience, the `adb shell` approach has the best chances (even better if you have root access).

Comment: @Izzy Isn't adb a tad slow when transferring big files, though?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman compared to MTP? *ROFL* And then, OP wants to move files within the device, so that's not relevant (it's no `adb pull` – though in my experience, even that is faster than transferring via MTP (but then again, what is not?))

Comment: @Izzy Can't argue with that. I still don't get why Google picked MTP to begin with.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman if you just got your first Android device ever, without any "depth knowledge" in advance, and plugged it into your computer – what would you end up with? Besides, Nikhil is lucky he didn't try that from Windows and lost all those files, if that bug wasn't yet fixed …

Comment: @Izzy Ah, "that" bug. I don't even want to remember.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I was never affected. Don't use either MTP nor Windows :)`</OT>` // **Nikhil:** Have you tried that? If you have no idea about ADB, our [adb tag wiki](/tags/adb/info) will be a good start.

Comment: @Izzy I'm using neither as well, starting from that day.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the guide. I would go through it. It previously sounded complicated.

Comment: @Nikhil once you got the knack it's easy (I use it almost daily, so I might be prejudiced). The only troubles are drivers (when you're on Windows), and then maybe getting the device properly detected for the first time (not hard either if you know how). A little self-promotion: my article [ADB for end-users](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/adb-for-end-users) might help getting you interested to dig-in – and started :)